# How to redirect to a particular form in html page using php header?

Tags: php, html, forms

In my `index.php` I have 2 forms which uses transition to move pages (Login to register and vice versa) when clicked on respective links. When I try to register in my backend I'm checking if user exist. If user does exist then I'm redirecting to index.php which is the main file. The problem is Login page is the default page which loads when index.php is refreshed. I tried running a js after running header function in backend code to click register page link in login page programatically. But it doesn't seem to work.

index.php -> contains 2 forms for register and login

```
<html>
<form action="register.php" method="post">
<button type=submit>
</form>

<form action="login.php" method="post">
<button type=submit>
</form>
</html>
```

register.php

```
if (user_exist){
  header("Location: index.php"); //redirects to index.php 
}
```

The above header redirects to index.php specifically login page but I need register page. Is there a way to use the form ID or class inside header to make that transition?

Comment: Give your submit buttons different names, then you can check for the existence of the corresponding $_POST entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the `header` function and specify the `Location`, like below:

```
header('Location: your/path/to/the/page');
```

Comment: index.php is the only file I need to redirect but it contains 2 forms in which I want to transition to register page as the page loads.